# Functionality of Openlayers compared to GoogleMaps

Tags: openlayers

I have to build something similar to www.flightradar24.com can i do it with Openlayers?

I am going to be using Linux Java/Tomcat maybe Oracle or Db2 , can i build something similar to www.flightradar24.com.

If you can answer in Yes or No that will be great.

Comment: Yes, that is possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers offers an extensive set of objects and functions that can be tailored to all your web mapping needs. Just check these examples (ie concepts similar to Flightradar24) for an opinion:

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/igc.html

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/feature-move-animation.html

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/geolocation-orientation.html